# Books related to Android middleware development

Tags: android

Everywhere I can find tons of books related to Android Application development - but I am really surprised that I have not been able to find a book which deals with middleware development. For example - I would really like to know how is the Multimedia Framework or RIL implemented or how does the Android Binder works.

I want to modify something in the middleware but sadly I can't find any comprehensive material on the same for example - add a service which interacts with the Multimedia Service. Yes there are articles on the web dealing with individual topics in some detail but no books covering anything below the Application Framework.

I can do this through Code browsing but it takes a lot of time just to gain a basic understanding.

Is there any link/book where this is covered in some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any books available on it at this time. I believe the fine folk behind [this training course](http://marakana.com/training/android/android_internals.html) on Android internals are working on a book on this topic, but AFAIK it is not yet ready as of the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

Karim Yaghmour's [embedded android book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) covers a fair bit of AOSP stuff.
And there's the [google groups](http://source.android.com/community/index.html). Support is indeed a bit sparse though. There are some good videos by Yaghmour and Tim Bird.

Answer (score 1):

Android Forensics: Investigation, Analysis and Mobile Security for Google Android by Andrew Hoog is very useful for me.

Marakana videos about Android Internals: [Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0), [Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFqELLB1Kk8)