# Learning resources for Android Open Source Project (AOSP)

Tags: android, git, repository, android-source

I can't find any good learning resource on AOSP. Can't find any books, or comperhensive web resources on that topic. Book that would cover all topics about it would be best. Like how to setup enviroment, download code, use repo/git, change basic things, make custom roms, etc etc. Is there any book like that? Or any other resource on web that have that info in one place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Books related to Android middleware development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123192/books-related-to-android-middleware-development)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Karim Yaghmour's [embedded android](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) covers a fair bit of AOSP stuff. There are some good videos by Tim Bird and Yaghmour, google for those.

If you want to create custom roms you probably want the [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/) and their [forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=564) or [cyanogen](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/).

Repo docs are fairly sparse: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537769/android-repo-documentation-available) post for that.

Answer (score 1):

The resource that really introduced me in this topic is [this](http://marakana.com/s/video_tutorial_android_internals_building_a_custom_rom_pt_1_of_2,269/index.html). There are two videos that give basic knowledge about the AOSP development process. After that, the best your choice is Google :) But then you'll know what to answer!

Answer (score -1):

this could be a start : http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: I know about that, but that are really basic stuff, and just cover downloading and bulding with one example, does not cover how to work/change the source later, best practices, etc.